# ArrayList of HashMaps to string, and then back to ArrayList of HashMaps

Tags: java, android

I have a `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` that I am using the `toString()` method on to store in a database.

Here is the code that I use to store it the `toString()` to a database (it works):

```
    HashMap<String, String> commentsHash = null; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> test2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

    for (int i=0; i < test.size(); i++)
    { 
        String timestamp = test.get(i).get("timestamp");
        String last_name = test.get(i).get("last_name"); 
        String first_name = test.get(i).get("first_name"); 
        String comment = test.get(i).get("comment");

        commentsHash = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

        commentsHash.put("creation_timestamp", timestamp); 
        commentsHash.put("first_name", first_name); 
        commentsHash.put("last_name", last_name); 
        commentsHash.put("comment", comment);   

        test2.add(commentsHash); 
    }

    dbHelper.addCommentsToMyLiPost(Integer.parseInt(sqlId), test2.toString());
```

Here is the method I want to use to convert a string to a `HashMap<String, String>`:

```
protected HashMap<String,String> convertToStringToHashMap(String text){
    HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\{\\}\\=\\, ]++");
    String[] split = p.split(text);
    for ( int i=1; i+2 <= split.length; i+=2 ){
        data.put( split[i], split[i+1] );
    }
    return data;
}
```

I have tried using .split(",") on the string to split the string into 2 parts, but instead of returning two, it returns 8.

Here is what the `toString()` method prints. It is an ArrayList of HashMaps, and I am trying to grab the two HashMaps that are inside of the ArrayList.

```
[{comment=hello, last_name=u1, first_name=u1, creation_timestamp=1404938643772}, {comment=hello2, last_name=u2, first_name=u2, creation_timestamp=1404963221598}]
```

Comment: why not create a class that holds your commentsHash data.  This class will have a `toString` method and a constrcutor that will be responsible for the to and from String'ing bit.  I guess your DB should also have a one to many with the many being being your comments.

Comment: Your String format seems close enough to JSON that it may be worth checking some libraries that automatically produce JSON out of java beans (and java objects out of JSON)

Comment: Agreed, why reinvent the serialization wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In convertToStringToHashMap, when you put your data into HashMap, the old value will be replaced since they have same key for each records, such as comment, last_name, etc.

```
    public static Map<String, Map<String, String>> convertToStringToHashMap(String text)
{
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\{\\}\\=\\, ]++");
    String[] split = p.split(text);

    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    int gap = 8;
    int key = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i + 2 <= split.length; i += 2)
    {
        data.put(split[i], split[i+1]);
        if((i + 1) % gap == 0)
        {
            map.put(String.valueOf(key++), data);
            data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.clear();
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

This will return a Map:

```
2={first_name=u2, last_name=u2, comment=hello2, creation_timestamp=1404963221598}
1={first_name=u1, last_name=u1, comment=hello, creation_timestamp=1404938643772}
```

Answer (score 1):

This program will recreate the whole list from the database entry

```
    Pattern firstPat = Pattern.compile("\\{.*?\\}");
    Matcher firstMat = firstPat.matcher(text);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(firstMat.find()){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String assignStrings = firstMat.group();
        String [] assignGroups = assignStrings.substring(1,assignStrings.length()-1).split("\\s*\\,\\s*");
        for(String assign:assignGroups){
            String [] parts = assign.split("\\=");
            map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
        list.add(map);
    }
    return list
```